# Slowdown on creating objects with many threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, asynchronous

I'm doing a project that spawn some hundreds of threads. All these threads are in a "sleeping" condition (they are locked on a Monitor object). I have noticed that if I increase the number of "sleeping" threads the program slow down very much. The "funny" thing is that looking at the Task Manager it seems that the greater the number of threads, the more free is the processor. I have narrowed the problem to object creation.

Can someone explain it to me?

I have produced a small sample to test it. It's a console program. It creates a thread for each processor and measure it's speed with a simple test (a "new Object()" ). No, the "new Object()" isn't jitted away (try if you don't trust me). The main thread show the speed of each thread. Pressing CTRL-C, the program spawns 50 "sleeping" threads. The slow down begins with just 50 threads. With around 250 it's very visible on the Task Manager that the CPU isn't 100% used (on mine it's 82%).

I have tried three methods of locking the "sleeping" thread: Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend() (bad, bad, I know :-) ), a lock on an already locked object and a Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite). It's the same. If I comment the row with the new Object(), and I replace it with a Math.Sqrt (or with nothing) the problem isn't present. The speed doesn't change with the number of threads. 
Can someone else check it? Does anyone knows where is the bottle neck?

Ah... you should test it in Release Mode WITHOUT launching it from the Visual Studio.
I'm using XP sp3 on a dual processor (no HT). I have tested it with the .NET 3.5 and 4.0 (to test the different framework runtimes)

```
namespace TestSpeed
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading;

    class Program
    {
        private const long ticksInSec = 10000000;
        private const long ticksInMs = ticksInSec / 1000;
        private const int threadsTime = 50;
        private const int stackSizeBytes = 256 * 1024;
        private const int waitTimeMs = 1000;

        private static List<int> collects = new List<int>();
        private static int[] objsCreated;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            objsCreated = new int[Environment.ProcessorCount];
            Monitor.Enter(objsCreated);

            for (int i = 0; i < objsCreated.Length; i++)
            {
                new Thread(Worker).Start(i);
            }

            int[] oldCount = new int[objsCreated.Length];

            DateTime last = DateTime.UtcNow;

            Console.Clear();

            int numThreads = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl-C to generate {0} sleeping threads, Ctrl-Break to end.", threadsTime);

            Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.SpecialKey != ConsoleSpecialKey.ControlC)
                {
                    return;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < threadsTime; i++)
                {
                    new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        /* The same for all the three "ways" to lock forever a thread */
                        //Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend();
                        //Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
                        lock (objsCreated) { }
                    }, stackSizeBytes).Start();

                    Interlocked.Increment(ref numThreads);
                }

                e.Cancel = true;
            };

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(waitTimeMs);

                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);

                DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

                long ticks = (now - last).Ticks;

                Console.WriteLine("Slept for {0}ms", ticks / ticksInMs);

                Thread.MemoryBarrier();

                for (int i = 0; i < objsCreated.Length; i++)
                {
                    int count = objsCreated[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} [{1} Threads]: {2}/sec    ", i, numThreads, ((long)(count - oldCount[i])) * ticksInSec / ticks);
                    oldCount[i] = count;
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                CheckCollects();

                last = now;
            }
        }

        private static void Worker(object obj)
        {
            int ix = (int)obj;

            while (true)
            {
                /* First and second are slowed by threads, third, fourth, fifth and "nothing" aren't*/

                new Object();
                //if (new Object().Equals(null)) return;
                //Math.Sqrt(objsCreated[ix]);
                //if (Math.Sqrt(objsCreated[ix]) < 0) return;
                //Interlocked.Add(ref objsCreated[ix], 0);

                Interlocked.Increment(ref objsCreated[ix]);
            }
        }

        private static void CheckCollects()
        {
            int newMax = GC.MaxGeneration;

            while (newMax > collects.Count)
            {
                collects.Add(0);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < collects.Count; i++)
            {
                int newCol = GC.CollectionCount(i);

                if (newCol != collects[i])
                {
                    collects[i] = newCol;
                    Console.WriteLine("Collect gen {0}: {1}", i, newCol);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, you should not have many more than (cpucount) threads.  Between (cpucount+2) and (cpucount*2) are good rules of thumb (and on your system, both come out to 4).  Use queues of asynchronous I/O operations to keep the few threads busy instead of sleeping.  The only time a thread should be waiting is when contended for a lock.

Comment: I'm doing a "slow-motion" coroutines. The "switch time" between threads is irrelevant, so I can use threads (I have about a "switch"/second, so even if it loses some ms to make the switch between the old thread and the new thread I don't have any problem). There are always a number of threads running equal to the processor But if sleeping threads slow down everything, then I have a problem. No, I can't use the async library of MS, because it's "fake". It "rewrites" your program. I have to use some preexisting libraries.

Comment: Have you considered using the TPL instead of explicitly creating threads? That way the framework can decide the most appropriate number of native threads to do the work.

Comment: @Richard My problem was that I wanted coroutines, and .NET doesn't implement them. I was simulating them using multiple threads. I had even tried using the Async CTP, but pre-refresh it was quite slow. I have to retry it post-refresh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My *guess* is that the problem is that garbage collection requires a certain amount of cooperation between threads - something either needs to check that they're all suspended, or ask them to suspend themselves and wait for it to happen, etc. (And even if they *are* suspended, it has to tell them not to wake up!)

This describes a "stop the world" garbage collector, of course. I believe there are at least two or three different GC implementations which differ in the details around parallelism... but I suspect that all of them are going to have *some* work to do in terms of getting threads to cooperate.

Comment: I have tried the "server" GC. It allocs a GC and a heap for each processor. The app scales better. With 100 Threads it loses "only" a 10% of speed on allocation of objects.

Comment: The more tests I do the more I'm convinced it's the GC. It's very difficult to "benchmark" the GC and distinguish its time from the time for the creation of the objects, but in the end this doesn't change anything from my POV: many threads = slow "new" objects (at least because new objects cause GC Collection). Server GC = Good when many threads. I could try object pooling but I think it would increase complexity... I'll see. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Start Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab.  View + Select columns, tick "Page Fault Delta".  You'll see the impact of allocating hundreds of megabytes, just to store the stacks of all these threads you created.  Every time that number blips for your process, your program blocks waiting for the operating system paging in data from the disk into RAM.

TANSTAAFL, There ain't no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: 1 MB user mode stack space plus another 1 MB native mode stack space, default size for each thread on creation.

Comment: @Chris, there is no native mode stack, one stack serves both.  However, every thread that's created also has a 24 KB kernel mode stack.

Comment: @Hans, thanks for the clarification, I meant kernel in place of native, but I thought this size was also 1MB.

Comment: I'm doing threads with a stack of 256kb. The memory isn't truly allocated, only the virtual space. The delta is stable at around 32. 100 thread * 256kb = 25mb. I'm not testing it on a C64, you know? :-) I have 3gb of memory.

Comment: "Stable at round 32" is not good, only 0 is good.  The CLR commits the entire stack, it is not just reserved like it is in native code.  Look at the other processes listed, difference is that they don't create hundreds of threads.

Comment: Without "sleeping" threads it's still stable at 32. I'm measuring relative speed, not absolute speed. And looking at the Task Manager, the memory is only reserved (50 threads at 256 kb increases much the virtual (12 mb) memory but nearly nothing the memory used)

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here is the GC in action. When you attach a debugger to your process you will see that many exceptions of the form

```
Unknown exception - code e0434f4e (first chance)
```

are thrown. This are exceptions caused by the GC to resume a suspended thread. As you know it is strongly discouraged to call Suspend/ResumeThread inside your process. This is even more true in managed world. The only authority which can do this safely is the GC. 
When you set a breakpoint at SuspendThread you will see

```
0118f010 5f3674da 00000000 00000000 83e36f53 KERNEL32!SuspendThread
0118f064 5f28c51d 00000000 83e36e63 00000000 mscorwks!Thread::SysSuspendForGC+0x2b0 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0118f154 5f28a83d 00000001 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::SuspendEE+0x194 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0118f17c 5f28c78c 00000000 00000000 0000000c mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration+0x136 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0118f208 5f28a0d3 002a43b0 0000000c 00000000 mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::try_allocate_more_space+0x15a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0118f21c 5f28a16e 002a43b0 0000000c 00000000 mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::allocate_more_space+0x11 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0118f23c 5f202341 002a43b0 0000000c 00000000 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::Alloc+0x3b (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0118f258 5f209721 0000000c 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!Alloc+0x60 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0118f298 5f2097e6 5e2d078c 83e36c0b 00000000 mscorwks!FastAllocateObject+0x38 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
```

that the GC does try to suspend all of your threads before he can do a full collection. On my machine (32 bit, Windows 7, .NET 3.5 SP1) the slowdown is not so dramatic. I do see a linear dependency between the thread count and the CPU (non) usage. It seems you are seeing increased costs for each GC because the GC has to suspend more threads before it can do a full collect. Interestingly the time is spent mainly in usermode so the kernel is not the limitting factor.

I do net see a way how you could get around that except using less threads or using unmanaged code. It could be that if you host the CLR by yourself and use Fibers instead of physical threads that the GC will scale much better. Unfortunately this feature was [cut out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinoviehland/archive/2005/09/15/469642.aspx) during the relase cycle of .NET 2.0. Since it is now 6 years later there is little hope that it will be added ever again.

Besides from your thread count the GC is also limitted by the complexity of your object graph. Have a look at this ["Do You Know The Costs Of Garbage?"](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2011/08/13/146515.aspx).

Comment: +1 Yeah I had discovered it was the GC that was creating the problem. He probably tries to suspend even threads that are already Waiting for something, so it's O(n) with n = total number of threads instead of O(m) with m = the number of running threads. Sadly I had already researched the Fiber trick and I knew it was cut out :-( And the older Async CTP had some problems where it was slow to run a Task that terminated immediately without waiting for something else (they should have solved it with the newer Async CTP but I began workin on another project in the meantime)

Comment: I think the reason why it cannot be O(m) is that if you wait e.g. with a timeout that you some threads might wake up in the middle of a GC. Besides that you could wake up a thread from which the GC thinks that it is suspended while it does supend all threads.

Comment: They could have solved it in other ways. The various Wait don't need to communicate directly to the OS. Their restart could have been "mediated" by the GC. They chose to do it this way, we have to work with it.