# Multithreaded app in multicore environment - weird load per core

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, multicore, task-parallel-library

Given environment: Xeon processor with 16 cores, OS - Win 2008 server R2.

Given application (.Net/C#) before paralleling loads 1 core at almost 100%.
Obvious solution to make some profit was to use .Net 4 parallel task library to speed application up X-times. 
Suppose the part of application that is paralleled is really appropriate - no locking occurs between threads (no shared resources, each parallel task is completely independent).
But to my regret the profit is really low - 16-threaded app works approx. 2 times faster than sequential.

Here is the first illustration - 16 threads on 16 cores

[image: 16]

It seems really weird - each task is equal but first 8 cores are loaded at almost same level (~30%) and other 8 have progressively descending load.

So, I've tried different configurations, for example 8 threads on 16 cores

[image: 8]

Looks like 8 threads are all runnin on 8 cores and threads are not transfered from one core to another. Moreover, on 8 cores average core load is greater than on 16.

I did some research via profiler - each thread has same behaviour like in single threaded case in terms of percentage of time spent in different methods. Only (and mean) difference is absolute time - it gets greater and greater with the growth of thread number (like if the performance of each core was degrading)

So the main tendencies that I cant explain - more threads mean lower average load per core and integral cpu usage is about 20-25% at maximum. And each operation in thread runs slower with the growth of the number of threads.

Any ideas to explain this weird things?

**UPD**

After applying Server GC the picture has changed significantly

8 threads on 16 cores illustration:

[image: 8AfterServerGC]

12 threads on 16 cores illustration:

[image: 12AfterServerGC]

15 threads on 16 cores illustration:

[image: 15AfterServerGC]

So, looks like cpu usage is increasing with the growth of core number. 
First thing that botheres me is that i t looks like all of cores are used and threads are jumping from core to core, so overall performance is not as good.

Second thing is that app maximum speed is at 12 cores, 15 cores give same results, 16 cores are even slower.

What is the possible reason?

Comment: Just to be sure... Are you using the Server GC? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423951/c-gc-for-server It COULD be that the problem is connected to GC.

Comment: This is a good idea to use, if you're not already using it.  However, I doubt this is a server GC issue, as that tends to cause the load to change over time, as well as typically is visible in the memory consumption  - it looks like this server still has 35GB of ram free, so I doubt GC pressure is the (main) problem...

Comment: @Reed The other GC stop all the threads when they collect. And they consume more and more CPU the greater the number of threads because they need to spinwait for the other thread to go to a point where GC can start collecting. It happened something similar to me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969963/slowdown-on-creating-objects-with-many-threads

Comment: Thanks, Xanatos your info and link helped to solve the issue. Server GC gave massive performance boost :) And it seems much more scalable now.

Comment: ooops, performance indeed increased, but scalacility is still not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you are seeing is often an indication of an I/O bottleneck.  If your disks or network are running full-out to provide data to these calculations (or handle the results), then you could run it on a million cores with no additional benefit.  I'd suggest using [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to examine network and disk I/O and see if there is an issue there before trying to get further into why this isn't parallelizing well.

Comment: I agree with Chris. The behavior you're describing is highly consistent with the CPU threads blocking while awaiting some (disk/network) IO function to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like you have no synchronization internal to your method, the problem is likely in the partitioning.

Given that you're using the TPL, work must get sent to cores based on a partitioner.  However, the actual source `IEnumerable<T>` is not thread safe, so that requires access via a single core.  This, in effect, will often lead to performance characteristics like the one you are showing above if the actual work is small compared to the number of items.

The way around this is to use the [Partitioner class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.aspx) to pre-partition your work items into blocks, and then iterate through the "blocks" of items in parallel.  For details, see [How to: Speed Up Small Loop Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853.aspx).

Comment: It's not the case - amount of work per unit is massive, but thx for iseful info about partitioner, I'd use it anyway.

Comment: Well main thing to do is a lot of calculations for each account from a bunch of accounts. Accounts are partitioned (now via Partitioner class ;) ) into blocks and each block gets processed in own thread.

Comment: @Roger: Are the calculations purely numerical?  Have you profiled to see if there is any IO or Network contention?

Comment: Calculations are purely numerical, I have to find out but no IO/Network shouldn't be hit as soon as all required additional data resides in RAM and all results are stored in RAM. But for some unknown reason app scales badly. Server GC gave a massive perfomance boost, but then I found that 16 threads version isn't faster than 12 threads. So further investigation is needed.

Comment: @Roger: Have you profiled it yet?  The concurrency visualizer in VS as well as a good perf. app might give some clues - especially if you look at any contention in the concurrency vizualizer.

Comment: Reed, I've updated the story. Would be thankful for your opinion on the updated picture.